# Unable to debug using iOS 8.1 device

Tags: ios, xcode6

I just upgraded my iPhone5s to iOS 8.1 from 8.0.2 and now XCode says it is an ineligible device and I can't debug on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Apple will usually release an update to fix this within a couple of days...

Comment: Upgrade your `xcode6` to `xcode6.1` then it should work

Comment: @Chris right they will hopefully.

Comment: They recently released it. Didn't see it in my auto-updates tab, had to search for it manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to install Xcode 6.1. Once you do, connect your iOS 8.1 device so the symbols can be processed. Once this is done you will be able to use the iOS 8.1 device with Xcode 6.1, 6.0, or earlier versions.